# ASP.NET MVC one particular view model property becoming null on returning to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post, actionresult

In ASP.NET MVC I have a view that's a form, and I want to be able to save the form and then it returns back to the same page showing the data you entered after saving the data to the database. I'm sure I'm just doing something stupid (this is pretty new to me), but there are some properties that I want to persist and I am setting them on the view model before I return, and I have `@Html.HiddenFor` inside my view's form. My confusion is that of these items are retained, and some aren't. So I have the following inside my FormController (methods and names have been simplified for brevity):

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? p, int? c)
        {
            FormViewModel model = new FormViewModel();
            model.p = p;
            model.c = c;
            model.dateStarted = DateTime.Now;
            return View(model);
        }

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Index(FormViewModel m)
        {
            Form form;
            bool shouldUpdate = false;
            if (m.formID != null) // m.formID is always null, but m.p, c, dateStarted aren't
            {
                shouldUpdate = true;
                form = getFormnWithId((int)m.formID); //gets from database
            }
            else
            {
                form = new Form(m);
            }

            if (shouldUpdate)
            {
                editForm(form);  //edit existing entry
            }
            else {
                addForm(form);  //add to database
            }
                m.formID = form.Id;  // formn.Id is valid because the form has been updated with its Id after being added to the database
                m.p = form.p;
                m.c = form.c;

                return View(m);
        }
```

Inside my view (cshtml) file I have `@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.formID)` as well as for other properties I want to persist but aren't being set in the form directly.
The formID however, is not persisting, while the other items (represented by c and p and dateStarted) are fine. If I remove the HiddenFor for those other fields, then they don't work. I click save each time, and formID is null in the post, but it's definitely set after the form has been added to the database and the value of the formID is definitely getting sent to the view. I just don't understand why it comes back null but the other properties don't.

Here's what the model looks like:

```
public class FormViewModel
{
     public Nullable<int> formID {get; set;}
     public Nullable<int> c { get; set; }
     public Nullable<int> p { get; set; }
     public System.DateTime dateStarted { get; set; }
     //+ other form properties
}
```

View:

...

```
<label for="submit-form" class="btn btn-default">Save</label>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal col-md-12">
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
        <!-- various form fields -->
        </div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.dateStarted)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.dateStarted)<br />  <!-- just to see it while testing-->
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.c)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.c)<br />
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.p)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.p)<br />
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.formID)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.formID)
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" name="Command" class="btn btn-default hidden" id="submit-form" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

}
```

Comment: inspect hidden field in firebug or chrome dev tools to check what's its value

Comment: Can you post your view please

Comment: Where are you actually setting a value for `formid`?  I don't see it in your get request method.

Comment: It's in the get request, it's set in the post request after the form has been added to the database. When the view first loads there's no formID yet because the form hasn't been saved to the database.

Comment: You need to post your View as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I see you are setting the `Form.Id` in the POST request, your issue is that you are not following the PRG (Post, Redirect, Get) pattern.  You are returning the same view from your POST method without any type of redirect.  As a result, the model binder is holding on to the ***previous*** value of Form.Id, which was null.  The reason that the model binder holds on to previous values is mainly for validation purposes (if the ModelState has an error, you can return the view, the properties remain as the user entered them along with the ModelState errors collection)

To fix this, you either need to redirect to another action or issue `ModelState.Clear()` in your code before you return the view.

```
   m.formID = form.Id;  // form.Id is valid because the form has been 
   //updated with its Id after being added to the database
   m.p = form.p;
   m.c = form.c;
   ModelState.Clear();

   return View(m);
```

Comment: I was stumped trying to figure out why it worked for some properties and not the others. Was trying to figure out how they were different. Feels so obvious now that the other ones were set before the view loaded and this one wasn't. Thanks so much!

Comment: Would redirecting to another action be better practice than returning to the same view?

Comment: Best practice is to redirect after a POST.  Basically, create an Edit method that takes an int as a parameter, which is your form Id.  Then pull the form from the database and return the view.  You can reuse the current view since not much is different.

Comment: Yea, it's just a big pain to map the database form to the view model (as opposed to vice versa) because it has all these checkboxes that are grouped differently in the view (whereas they're all in the same table in the database). So to avoid having to regenerate the model from the database I figured this was much easier.

Comment: Typically, I have a method in a service layer (outside of the controller) that would build the view model for me.  One function can return the view model for both the create and edit methods.  (Have a nullable int that is if has value, pull stuff from db, else create new form)

Comment: Building the actual method would be annoying (it would be big and messy) in this case, no matter where it is, because the form view model structure is a bit complicated with the checkbox groupings. I think I'll try to figure out a better way to implement the form first.